# Incomplete download of the file using urllib.request

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

There is a long list of files that I would like to download via a python script. When I try to download manually (by copying the url and paste it into the address bar), it shows me the full size of the file and download it completely:
[image: Downloading one of the files manually]

However, when I try to download using `urllib.request`

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://..... .zip'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, './myfile.zip')
```

It only download the first 64 KB of the file. How I can download the whole file using such a Python script?

Comment: What status code and mimetype is returned if you make a get request to that url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download large file in python with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests)